# Oracle ASMM - Are specific values ignored?

Tags: oracle

I've inherited an 11.2.0 DB and I'm trying to do some performance tuning.

At present, it's started from a pfile and it looks like ASMM is enabled (SGA_TARGET, SGA_MAX_TARGET and PGA_AGGRIGATE_TARGET are all set). My question is, there are SGA structures also set in the pfile, are they ignored in favour of the ASMM?

E.g. I have the following:

```
  shared_pool_size         = 800M
  large_pool_size          = 32M
  java_pool_size           = 160M
```

Probably a fundamental question, but I'm struggling to get a definitive answer online.

Comment: What does `v$parameter` say?

Answer (score 1):

These are minimum values for those components.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16638/memory.htm#i58728

"If these automatically tuned memory pools had been set to nonzero values, those values are used as minimum levels by Automatic Shared Memory Management. You would set minimum values if an application component needs a minimum amount of memory to function properly."